# Program should not work as per `C faq` but it works

Tags: c, coredump

I was just going through the `c-faq`, when I came across [this](http://c-faq.com/struct/retcrash.html) page. I stated that the following program will have a core dump:

```
struct list {
    char *item;
    struct list *next;
}

/* Here is the main program. */

main(argc, argv)
{}
```

The reason they told for the core dump to happen was:

> A missing semicolon at the end of the structure declaration causes main to be declared as returning a structure. (The connection is hard to see because of the intervening comment.) Since structure-valued functions are usually implemented by adding a hidden return pointer (see question 2.9), the generated code for main() tries to accept three arguments, although only two are passed (in this case, by the C start-up code). See also questions 10.9 and 16.4.

Although, when I ran this program online over [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php), it worked perfectly and the program did run till the end. Also, when I compiled this program using gcc, I got no warnings.

I was surprised, as the program should have not runned till the end. Can someone tell me why this program works? If it is correct, why is it mentioned that the program will not work (any chance it might crash?).

**NOTE:** Please do not post comments such as use `int main` because I have just copy pasted the code, and in actual, I use the proper way.

Comment: Can anyone with more reputation make a tag for `c-faq`?

Comment: Run it in standards-compliant mode, you should see it fail. GCC allows lots of things, which should fail according to the spec. Like not specifying a return type for `main`.

Comment: @meskobalazs, what do you mean? I am actually a beginner in c.

Comment: What version of gcc are you using? When I compile it I get a warning "test.c:9: warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int'"

Comment: E.g. `gcc --std=c99` will compile it against the C99 standard.

Comment: @jcoder, I am using gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: It will lead to *undefined behavior*, and one of the alternatives of that is to *seemingly* work.

Comment: @meskobalazs, it gives warnings, but stills runs successfully.

Comment: I read that the program will run until the end, but *then* create a core dump. Did you check if there was core dump created afterwards?

Comment: @mistapink, no, there was no core dump created.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, can you just explain me how it is UB? As I mentioned, i am a beginner. I could not understand the reason for UB.

Comment: Not returning anything from a function declared to return something is UB.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings.  Then fix those warnings.  After all, the compiler knows the language much better than us mere mortals.  I compile the posted code with: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu99`  (notice the single `-` before `std`)  this results in 6 major warnings,  all easy to fix (and fixing some of them, like the return type for `main()` will expose more warnings, like the missing trailing semicolon on the struct definition.   No, this will not produce a core dump; however, it will produce an executable that contains lots of undefined behaviour.

Comment: The C Faq does not say that this program will crash or core dump.  On the page you link to , "Q:" stands for "Question", and "A:" stands for "Answer". Read the "A:" part to see what the FAQ's advice is.

Comment: @M.M, so you mean to say that my program also might crash, and might not? If yes, then why does the question clearly mention the program crashes and has a core dump.

Comment: @AshishAhuja because the person who asked the question experienced a core dump . That doesn't mean all people in the world would also get a core dump, just that one person did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a misreading of the C FAQ.

The C FAQ explains why the code is incorrect, but it does not say that the code is guaranteed to crash.  Here's part of the section you quoted:

> Since structure-valued functions are **usually** implemented by adding a hidden return pointer...

I've added emphasis.  The C FAQ is explaining why the code *might* crash.  The code is incorrect in either case.  (In theory, the behavior could be *implementation-defined,* but it is extremely unlikely that your C implementation defines what happens in this case.)

On many systems (ABIs), functions which return structures will use registers for the return value if the structures are small enough.  I don't know what the limit is for common x64 ABIs, but two words (two pointers) is fairly small.

Comment: Thanks, but do please read the question in the page mentioned. The question says: _"This program works correctly, but it dumps core after it finishes. Why?"_. It clearly says that the program dumps core after it finishes. +1 for good explanation.

Comment: @AshishAhuja yes, that is the *question*.  The answer lies in the *answer* part (introduced by "A:" on that page).

Comment: @M.M, oops, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This program does not appear to be illegal according to the standard.
Lets look at the program first cleaned up:

```
struct list {
    char *item;
    struct list *next;
} main(argc, argv){}
```

Ok, so we are declaring main as returning a struct list.
Let us now look at the valid declarations of main according to ISO 9899:2011
(C11) though C99 is largely the same.

> It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters
>   or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared). or in some other implementation-defined manner.

(Slightly abridged)
It appears to me that this therefore squarely falls into the third definition of "some other implementation-defined manner" meaning it is in the realm of implementation defined behavior.

Therefore this is not an issue of C at all but instead up to the compiler in use and thus largely irrelevant to a C faq. You would need to look into your compiler's documentation for what (if anything) this is defined to do.

Most likely your compiler does not define it at all in which case it is undefined and could thus result in any behavior at all including appearing to work or crashing.

Comment: "Some implementation-defined manner" means that your C implementation has to define that definition as valid, which I'm thinking it doesn't.

Comment: @DietrichEpp However the OP doesn't mention a compiler or give a compiler tag so I am answering only insofar as C specifies the behaviour.

Comment: But this isn't why it works... unless you can find an implementation where this behavior is defined.  "Implementation-defined" is a specific term defined in the C standard.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It doesn't matter why it works according to the C language in an abstract sense. I am aware of the meaning of implementation defined behavior. I am also stating that this isnt something that C completely defines so cant be answered in terms of the language alone. If the querstion were about a particular implementation I am sure it would be simple to reverse engineer it to find out what it did.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the C standard doesn't define what happen here.  But I disagree about whether this is implementation-defined behavior.  It *could* be, in theory, but it probably isn't, because it is unlikely that an actual implementation would define the behavior for such a construction.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I do get your point, I suppose in essence it comes down to implementation defined behavior being undefined should the implementation not define it. However if it were simply undefined the answer would merely be "Its undefined, anything could happen" but in this case it is even less clear cut in the sense implementation could define more. Now I give it is highly unlikely this specific signature would be catered for but I would not be surprised if a compiler (particularly an embedded one) might say it simply doesn't care what main returns in which case it would become defined.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Either way, I have tried to add a note mentioning that it is likely to be undefined in a particular compiler and that in that case it will be undefined (permitting anything to happen)